# Play a Video in Flutter Webview in full screen

Tags: android, flutter, browser, webview

I am trying to play a video in full-screen mode in Flutter WebView. The video is from an anime website. I couldn't find any solutions online, so I am writing here hoping to find an answer that will not only help me but also other people facing a similar issue.

This is what i use for the webview:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://website.example',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
            _controller = controller;
          },
          navigationDelegate: (navigation) {
            if (_isWhitelisted(navigation.url)) {   // a white list of websites which are allowed to get access to 
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            } else {
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
          },
          onPageFinished: (url) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            if (uri.host == 'website.example' && [
              '',
              '/',
              '/index.html',
              '/#/',
            ].contains(uri.path)){
              // Inject JavaScript code to hide the first child div after class "container"
              _controller.evaluateJavascript('''
        var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
        container.children[0].style.display = 'none';
  
        // Hide any element of the class "col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
          elements[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      ''');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried to edit the manifest.xml file, but that didn't work. Additionally, I attempted to create a full-screen button, but it also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using WebView, use this library to load a video from a URL: https://pub.dev/packages/video_player